# ¿How do i resize a a custom view?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

Before ask this, i've look up a lot of questions asking the same, and the answer was the same:

```
mylayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(theWidthIWant,TheHeightIWant));
//                                |    
//                                -->or your container's layout
```

So I used this code to solve my problem: I'm making a game that use some buttons to move the character, the buttons are in a custom layout that extends from `LinearLayout` called `SquareLayout` (yes, you guessed, it's a square), but I want it's height(or width, because both width and height will be always the same) to be the half of its parent(or what's the same, the screen), so I'm using this code in the onCreate method just like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RelativeLayout rl1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl1);
    SquareLayout sq1 = (SquareLayout)findViewById(R.id.square);
    int width = sq1.getWidth()/2,height = sq1.getHeight()/2;
    sq1.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,height));
}
```

But it does not show nothing on the screen. If i set the width and height to a number, it works finely, but not using variables.

Comment: Um, why are you setting the `SquareLayout` size to be half of its current size?

Comment: @CommonsWare, well, i want the "buttons panel" to be like the buttons of Minecraft PE or any another game that uses buttons to move its character.

Comment: I am a bit rusty on android layouts, but sq1 is a `SquareLayout` hence a `LinearLayout` and you try to use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`. Plus you said you want your layout to be half the size of its parent, but you are setting it to be half of its own size.

Comment: Its Ok, its extends from `LinearLayout`, but it's on a RelativeLayout, if i would put `LinearLayout.layoutParams` it would give me an error, because it extends from a LinearLayout but it's container is a RelativeLayout(I forgot to write that). Like it's shown in the image, sq1 has the same height of it's container, so it's the same thing to put "sq1.getHeight()" and "rl1.getHeight"

Comment: "well, i want the "buttons panel" to be like the buttons of Minecraft PE or any another game that uses buttons to move its character" -- that does not explain why you are setting its size to be half of its current size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe sq1 is not visible at the moment when you are requesting width-height, so it returns null, try:

```
SquareLayout sq1 = (SquareLayout)findViewById(R.id.square);
sq1.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   int width = sq1.getWidth()/2,height = sq1.getHeight()/2;
                 sq1.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,height));
                }
            });
```